# ¿Por que me da un hash diferente al generar un apk release que cuando lo hago en debug?

Tags: login, flutter, facebook, hash

Estoy queriendo implementar la autentificación con **facebook** por lo tanto, para pruebas genere un **hash** usando lo siguiente.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Funciona correctamente a excepción de algunos mensajes de error en consola, pero por lo menos se autentifica.

Paso a generar el **apk release** y para que funcione todo sin problemas genero un **hash** nuevo que en teoría es para  **release**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

al probar la autentificación me sale el siguiente mensaje de error

> Invalid key hash. The key hash **un hash diferente al mio** does not
>   match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at **url de
>   facebook**

NOTA: Realice diferentes pruebas con el **hash** y cambia dependiendo del **-alias** que uno le coloque.

¿Entonces que **hash** se genera al crear el apk release ? ¿y como puedo generarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes generar un keystore para producción puedes seguir los pasos para [Preparación de una aplicación de Android para su lanzamiento](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

*Voy a poner un extracto aquí*

**Para Mac/Linux** 
Generar keystore

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Esto te pedirá ingresar contraseña y alias. Esto debes guardarlo en un lugar seguro.

Una vez completado se creará un keystore `key.jks` en tu directorio actual. Para compilar para producción debes configurar en `<app dir>/android/key.properties`

```
storePassword=<password ingresado en el paso anterior>
keyPassword=<password ingresado en el paso anterior>
keyAlias=key
storeFile=<ubicación de keystore, ejemplo: /<Users>/<proyecto1>/key.jks>
```

Para obtener el hash de keystore puedes usar

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath>
```

Para generar Hash para Facebook debes encodear a base64:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Si de hecho realice todos esos pasos, pero resulta que en **Facebook** agregue el **HASH**  que genere con el base64 y al probar el apk en modo release, me arroja un error mostrándome una **HASH** diferente diciendo que no coincide con ninguna de las que se proporsiono en **Facebook developers**

Comment: Has realizado este paso? https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle

Comment: Si lo realice.. todos esos pasos ya están con forme a la documentación, al probar con el aliasName = key en consola me manda un error pero si me genera una **HASH** Solo que no es la misma que aparece al probar la autentificación con **Facebook**,  registre 3 **HASH** en facebook y nunguna es la que me sale en la app en modo **release**